# How a Constraint works?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to position elements like in a flow layout, for that I'm using RelativeLayouts and constraints. 
I want the Width to be calculated based on a percentage of the parent width. So basically my constraint it's something like this:

```
widthConstraint = Constraint.RelativeToParent((RelativeLayout parent) =>
{
    return parent.Width * percentage;
});
```

It works really well in most cases. However I have a case with a label where its width must be 50% of the parent, but when is rendered its width it's actually that of the text inside (autosize). I put a breakpoint in the `widthConstraint` and it returns the 50%, so I can't understand why `Xamarin.Forms` doesn't take into account this return value.

Someone knows how a constraint works in `Xamarin.Forms`? 
Besides the return value of the constraint it takes into account other parameter?

P.S: I'm working with the latest stable version `Xamarin.Forms 2.3.2.127`

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code example?

Comment: Actually it's a pretty large code with many other things for position and margin in RelativeLayout, and it's a very specific case. That why I wanted to know how the constraints takes the return values. But I trying to make a demo for this.